# Existence of solutions to diophantine quadratic form

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, quadratic-forms

Is there a general result about the existence of $($non-trivial$)$ solutions of the diophantine equation:

$$Ax^2 + By^2 = Cz^2$$

for $A,B,C$ known positive integers, pair-wise relatively prime?

What if we know $C$ is $1$ or $3?$

Comment: this is the same as asking for rational points on an ellipse.  you can get a rational parameterization of the ellipse by fixing a point on the ellipse and finding the other point of intersection of a line through the given point. so for rational slopes through one of the obvious (trivial) points, you get infinitely many solutions.

Comment: But then I'd need to find a point on the elipse, and I'm looking for *whether* there are rational points on the ellipse.  Once I've found one such point, I know that I can find infinitely many, yes :)

Comment: For example, if (A,B,C)=(5,2,1), there is no solution.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1513733/solving-a-diophantine-equation-of-the-form-x2-ay2-byz-cz2-with-the-co/1514030#1514030

Comment: Technically, actually there is 2 problem. One clarification of the existence of solutions, another search formula to parameterise them.

Comment: $$c\,{\left( {p}^{2}\,s-{b}^{2}\,c\,d\,s+2\,b\,d\,h\,p\right) }^{2}+d\,{\left( 2\,b\,c\,p\,s-h\,{p}^{2}+{b}^{2}\,c\,d\,h\right) }^{2}={\left( {p}^{2}+{b}^{2}\,c\,d\right) }^{2}\,\left( c\,{s}^{2}+d\,{h}^{2}\right) $$

Comment: @AlexSam formally, the solution of the equation $Ax^2+By^2=Cz^2$ using the solution of the equation  $Ax^2+By^2=Cz^2$  .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes; actually, this is one of the only classes of Diophantine equations for which such a result exists! First we will make some simplifying observations. Observe that it is pretty easy to tell what happens when $z = 0$, so suppose $z \neq 0$. Next observe that finding integer solutions is equivalent to finding rational solutions, and since we can scale all three variables by the same constant we can assume $z = 1$, so we are solving $Ax^2 + By^2 = C$ for rationals $x, y$.

It's a classical result that if there is one solution, there is a straightforward way to describe all of the other solutions: if $(x_0, y_0)$ is a solution, then any line of the form $(x_0 + at, y_0 + bt)$ where $a, b$ are fixed rationals intersects the curve $Ax^2 + By^2 = C$ in exactly one other point, and this intersection must be rational; conversely, every other rational solution arises in this way.

So it suffices to find a single solution. To do this the key is the [Hasse-Minkowski theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse%E2%80%93Minkowski_theorem), which tells you that solutions exist over $\mathbb{Q}$ if and only if they exist over $\mathbb{R}$ and over the [p-adic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number) $\mathbb{Q}_p$ for all primes $p$.

It is very easy to check if a solution exists over $\mathbb{R}$, so it suffices to check if solutions exist over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ for all $p$. If $p \nmid 2ABC$, then the [Chevalley-Warning theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chevalley%E2%80%93Warning_theorem) shows that the equation has a solution in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, and by [Hensel's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma) these solutions can be upgraded to solutions in $\mathbb{Z}_p \subset \mathbb{Q}_p$.

So we are reduced to checking the finitely many primes dividing $2ABC$. But for any particular such prime, this is more or less an application of [quadratic reciprocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity) together with Hensel's lemma again.

This is classical material; I think you can find a more thorough exposition in the beginning of Cassels' *Lectures on Elliptic Curves.*

Comment: Thanks.  My mathematics is rusty, but I had a feeling this was possible.

Comment: Let me take the opportunity to mention something which I think is amazing: there is _no such result_ for polynomials of degree $3$ or higher. We can't even prove such a result for the specific case of polynomials of degree $3$. There is a nice discussion of what is known (although it may be outdated by now) in Poonen's _Computing Rational Points on Curves_: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.10.2007

Comment: It seems like the final hard part is the case p=2. You cannot use Hensel's lemma mod 2, can you?

Comment: @Thomas: there is a more general version of Hensel's lemma which works here (and this is the version stated e.g. in the Wikipedia article). You need to verify if there are solutions mod 8, I think.

Answer (score 3):

As Qiaochu mentioned, this is a classical problem that is a prototypical example of an equation that is amenable to the *local-global* approach. Legendre obtained a complete solution by descent circa 1785. Later, as $p$-adic methods emerged, it was realized that Legendre's solution could be elegantly reformulated via such local-global techniques. You can find a nice readable four-page introduction on [pp. 238-242 of Harvey Cohn: Advanced Number Theory.](http://books.google.com/books?id=yMGeElJ8M0wC&pg=PA238)

Answer (score 1):

I would happily add Serre's book.

Comment: It would probably be a good idea to specify which book; I guess you mean _A Course in Arithmetic._

Comment: yes. It is that book.