# On products of ternary quadratic forms $\prod_{i=1}^3 (ax_i^2+by_i^2+cz_i^2) = ax_0^2+by_0^2+cz_0^2$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-equations, quadratic-forms

The equation,

$$ (ax_1^2+by_1^2)(ax_2^2+by_2^2) = ax_0^2+by_0^2\tag1$$

has the well-known solution when $a=b=1$,

$$ (x_1^2+y_1^2)(x_2^2+y_2^2) = (x_1 y_2 + x_2 y_1)^2 + (x_1 x_2 - y_1 y_2)^2$$

Hence the product of the sum of two squares is itself the sum of two squares.
If we use *one more factor*, then it has an identity for general $a,b$, namely,

$$ (ax_1^2+by_1^2)(ax_2^2+by_2^2)(ax_3^2+by_3^2) = ax_0^2+by_0^2\tag2$$

where,

$$x_0 =a \color{blue}{x_1 x_2 x_3} + b \big(-\color{blue}{x_1} y_2 y_3 + \color{blue}{x_2} y_1 y_3 + \color{blue}{x_3} y_1 y_2 \big)$$

$$y_0 =a \big(-x_2 x_3 \color{brown}{y_1} + x_1 x_3 \color{brown}{y_2} + x_1 x_2 \color{brown}{y_3}\big) + b \color{brown}{y_1 y_2 y_3}$$

High-lighted this way, one can immediately see the pattern.

**Q:** Is there a similar identity for *ternary* quadratic forms,

$$ (ax_1^2+by_1^2+cz_1^2)(ax_2^2+by_2^2+cz_2^2)(ax_3^2+by_3^2+cz_3^2) = ax_0^2+by_0^2+cz_0^2\tag3$$

such that $x_0, y_0, z_0$ are integer functions in terms of the other $x_i, y_i, z_i$ just like for $(2)$?

Comment: Well, first you have to solve the equation.  $$(a_1x_1^2+b_1y_1^2+c_1z_1^2)(a_2x_2^2+b_2y_2^2+c_2z_2^2)=ax^2+by^2+cz^2$$  Then you can move on to a more complicated formula.

Comment: @individ: The problem with that approach is that there might be no solution. For example, the equation $(1)$, namely, $$(ax_1^2+by_1^2)(ax_2^2+by_2^2) = ax_0^2+by_0^2$$ has no known solution for general $a,b$, but becomes solvable when a third factor is used like in $(2)$.

Comment: Isn't it a known theorem that there are such formulas for 2,4,8, and 16 terms, but no others? I can't remember where I saw that…

Comment: @KierenMacMillan:That is for $n$-nary quadratic forms with _unit_ coefficients for $=2,4,8$ (The case $n=16$ and higher already involves rational functions.) This post asks for more general coefficients.

Comment: In (2) and what follows, are there $\pm$ options like the two different options in (1) and what follows?

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII: In (2) and the following parameterization of $(x_0,y_0)$, are there $\pm$ options like the two different options applicable to (1)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there cannot be a completely general identity. There cannot even be such an identity for $(a,b,c)=(1,1,1)$, since
$$
(1+0+0)(1+1+1)(0+1+4) = 15
$$
and by [Legendre's three-square theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_three-square_theorem) $15$ cannot be written as the sum of three squares.

Since we can add factors of $(1+0+0)$ without changing the product, it is clear that additional factors cannot resolve the problem in this case.

Comment: Hm, that is rather deflating. I guess the next case would be, $$\prod_{i=1}^n (ax_i^2+by_i^2+cz_i^2+dt_i^2) = ax_0^2+by_0^2+cz_0^2+dt_0^2$$ for either $n=4$ or $5$.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII, works for $n=4$ because we get quaternion multiplication with $w^2 + a x^2 + b y^2 + ab z^2.$ Pretty sure  $w^2 + ac x^2 + bc y^2 + ab z^2$ also works. In both cases it is a multiplication of pairs of coefficient quadruples, $x_0 \, 1 + i x_1 \sqrt a + j x_2 \sqrt b + k x_3 \sqrt {ab}$