# Does the equation $x^2+23y^2=2z^2$ have integer solutions?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-equations

> I would like to show that the image of the norm map $\text N : \mathbb Z \left[\frac{1 + \sqrt{-23}}{2} \right] \to \mathbb Z$ does not include $2.$ I first thought that the norm map from $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-23}) \to \mathbb Q$ does not have $2$ as its image either, so I tried to solve the Diophantine equation $$x^2 + 23y^2 = 2z^2$$ in integers.

After taking congruences with respect to several integers, such as $2, 23, 4, 8$ and even $16,$ I still cannot say that this equation has no integer solutions. Then I found out that the map $\text{N}$ has a simpler expression and can be easily shown not to map to $2.$

But I still want to know about the image of $\text N,$ and any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: May I know the reason for down-vote to improve the next time? Thanks.

Comment: $7^2 + 23*1^2=2*6^2$.

Comment: And $3^{2}+23*1^{2}=2*4^{2}$.

Comment: And $6^2+23*2^2=2*8^2$.

Comment: $ \color{blue}{ \left(7u^2 + 10uv -3 v^2 \right)^2 + 23  \left(u^2 -2uv - v^2  \right)^2 = 8 \left( 3u^2 +  uv + 2 v^2 \right)^2}  $

Comment: The nice thing about quadratics like this is that if there are no non-trivial rational solutions, then there will be some modulus that proves the obstruction (or else it fails for trivial positivity reasons like $x^2 + y^2 = -z^2$).  Thus after trying enough congruences it makes sense to look for solutions instead.

Comment: Indeed, I shall have pondered more and tried some search before asking. Thanks again!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$x^2+23y^2=2z^2\iff x^2+(5y)^2=2(z^2+y^2)$.

Since the solutions of the equation $X^2+Y^2=2Z^2$ are given by the identity
$$(a^2+2ab-b^2)^2+(a^2-2ab-b^2)^2=2(a^2+b^2)$$ we can try $(y,z)=(a,b)$ taking care of one of $a^2+2ab-b^2$ or $a^2-2ab-b^2$ be equal to $5b$.

Taking for example $(y,z)=(1,4)$ we get the solution $(x,y,z)=(3,1,4)$.

Thus the proposed equation have solutions (which can be parametrized but I stop here).

Comment: Your first line just dawned on me! Thanks for this simple but beautiful  identity!

Comment: nice....................+1

Comment: $ \color{blue}{ \left(7u^2 + 10uv -3 v^2 \right)^2 + 23  \left(u^2 -2uv - v^2  \right)^2 = 8 \left( 3u^2 +  uv + 2 v^2 \right)^2}  $ gives all primitive solutions

Answer (score 5):

Conclusion: it is likely that the  parametrization
$$ \color{blue}{ \left(7u^2 + 10uv -3 v^2 \right)^2 + 23  \left(u^2 -2uv - v^2  \right)^2 = 8 \left( 3u^2 +  uv + 2 v^2 \right)^2}  $$
gives all solutions to $x^2 + 23 y^2 = 8 z^2$ with $\gcd(x,y,z) = 1.$  There is a theorem that all primitive solutions can be found with a small finite number of such parametrizations. This version is better than the one at the end of my discussion, $z$ is discriminant $-23$ rather than $-92,$ that is why there is no longer a problem about $z \equiv 2 \pmod 4.$ Live and learn.

If you wish to see how this does by computer (I advise this), with $z = 3u^2 + uv + 2 v^2 \leq M$ for some upper bound $M,$ we can demand
$$ |u| \leq \sqrt {\frac{8M}{23}}, $$
$$ |v| \leq \sqrt {\frac{12M}{23}}. $$

Here is a raw search for primitive solutions with $z \leq 100.$

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

```
    x    y    z
    3    1    2
    7    1    3
   25    1    9
    5    7   12
   15    7   13
   45    1   16
   59    7   24
    9   17   29
   81    7   31
   61   17   36
    1   23   39
  111    7   41
  105   17   47
  147    1   52
  149    7   54
   35   31   54
  135   31   71
   53   41   72
   63   41   73
  205   17   78
  163   31   78
   41   47   81
   73   49   87
  263    1   93
  259   17   96
```

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

Next is by parametrization, where it was necessary to use absolute values to get a nice ordering. In order to reduce repetition I took only $u \geq 0.$ I notice how not all $\pm$ signs occur in $x,y$ here. To get all types, one would need four slightly different parametrizations, $(x,y)$ as written, then $(x,-y),$ $(-x,y),$ $(-x,-y).$

```
    z             |x|  |y|   z              x    y    z              u    v
    2              3    1    2             -3   -1    2              0    1
    2              3    1    2             -3   -1    2              0   -1
    3              7    1    3              7    1    3              1    0
    9             25    1    9            -25    1    9              1   -2
   12              5    7   12              5    7   12              2   -1
   13             15    7   13             15   -7   13              1    2
   16             45    1   16             45   -1   16              2    1
   24             59    7   24            -59    7   24              2   -3
   29              9   17   29             -9   17   29              3   -2
   31             81    7   31            -81   -7   31              1   -4
   36             61   17   36             61  -17   36              2    3
   39              1   23   39             -1  -23   39              1    4
   41            111    7   41            111   -7   41              3    2
   47            105   17   47           -105   17   47              3   -4
   52            147    1   52           -147   -1   52              2   -5
   54            149    7   54            149    7   54              4    1
   54             35   31   54            -35   31   54              4   -3
   71            135   31   71            135  -31   71              3    4
   72             53   41   72             53  -41   72              2    5
   73             63   41   73             63   41   73              5   -2
   78            163   31   78           -163   31   78              4   -5
   78            205   17   78            205  -17   78              4    3
   81             41   47   81            -41  -47   81              1    6
   87             73   49   87            -73   49   87              5   -4
   93            263    1   93            263    1   93              5    2
   96            259   17   96           -259  -17   96              2   -7
    z             |x|  |y|   z              x    y    z              u    v
```

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

There is another way to talk about the behavior of the norm map. The binary quadratic forms of discriminant $-92$ are in three classes, reduced are $x^2 + 23 y^2,$ $3x^2 + 2xy + 8y^2,$ $3x^2 - 2xy + 8y^2.$

That is, under Gauss composition, the groups is cyclic order three and  $3x^2 + 2xy + 8y^2$ is a generator. It primitively represents $8.$ It also primitively represents infinitely many squares $z^2,$ and composition tells us that $8z^2$ is primitively represented by $x^2 + 23 y^2.$

The part about squares is best written in Dirichlet's version of composition, which was all we had until Bhargava gave other interpretations of Gauss. The form $3x^2 + 2xy + 8y^2$ is integrally equivalent ($SL_2 \mathbb Z$) to $3x^2 + 4 xy + 9 y^2.$

Dirichlet's methods tell us (page 49 in [Cox](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-1118390180.html), although the first edition has a typo, pasting corrected selection from second edition  ) that 
$$ \left( 3 u^2 + 4 uv + 9 v^2 \right)^2 = 9 U^2 + 4 UV + 3 V^2,   $$
where $$  U = u^2 - 3 v^2, \; \; \; V = 6uv + 4 v^2.  $$

Another arrangement of the symbols $a,a',B,C$ tells us
$$ \left( 9U^2 + 4 U V + 3 V^2 \right) \left(3 s^2 + 4 st + 9 t^2 \right) = 27 S^2 + 4 ST + T^2, $$
where
$$ S = Us-Vt, \; \; \; T = 9Ut + 3Vs +4Vt.  $$ Taking lower case $s=1,t=-1$ gives
$$ 8 \left(3 U^2 + 4 UV + 9 V^2 \right) = 27 S^2 + 4 ST + T^2, $$
where
$$ S = U +V, \; \; \; T = -9U + 3V - 4V = -9U -V.  $$
Finally
$$ (T+2S)^2 + 23 S^2 = 27 S^2 + 4 ST + T^2. $$

Put it together, we can, for example with $p$ prime, solve $x^2 + 23 y^2 = 2 p^2$ whenever $p = 3 u^2 + 2 uv + 8 v^2.$ This is possible for $p = 3$ and then for all $(23|p) = 1$ such that
$ w^3 - w + 1$ is irreducible $\pmod p.$ This last fact is not in Cox, it is class field theory from a 1991 article by Hudson and Williams.

Maybe I should summarize: we get an explicit formula for $x,y$ in
$$ x^2 + 23 y^2 = 8  \left( 3 u^2 + 4 uv + 9 v^2 \right)^2  $$
given $u,v$ arbitrary integers. That is,
$$ \color{blue}{ \left(-7u^2 + 6uv + 25 v^2 \right)^2 + 23  \left(u^2 + 6uv + v^2  \right)^2 = 8 \left( 3u^2 + 4 uv + 9 v^2 \right)^2}.  $$
Now that I've corrected some errors of mine (I was out of practice) the final formula can be checked easily enough.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this interpretation as quadratic forms and the solution following this line.

Comment: @awllower I may have been hasty. Were you asking how to describe the numbers represented by $x^2 + xy + 6 y^2?$

Comment: I don't think so: what I asked is already answered here.

Comment: @WilI Jagy: I read your quote Skolem to Albanese. I completely agree. The problem, with regard to the truth, and is almost always the case, is that who does not know these things well, prefers simplicity. Best regard.

Answer (score 1):

To solve such problems, it is necessary to use the formula.  [Solving a Diophantine equation of the form $x^2 = ay^2 + byz + cz^2$ with the constants $a, b, c$ given and $x,y,z$ positive integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1513733/solving-a-diophantine-equation-of-the-form-x2-ay2-byz-cz2-with-the-co/1514030#1514030)

The formula is written in a General form so I will have to solve the equation. For the equation.

$$23x^2+y_1^2=2z^2$$

Will do the replacement.  $y_1=x+ay$ The equation will look like.

$$(23+a^2)x^2+2axy+y^2=2z^2$$

And we need to find this number  $a$.

Using these formulae. And we will need to solve the Pell equation. $3$ use the formula.
$$q=\sqrt{4a^2+4(23+a^2)(2-1)}=2\sqrt{23+2a^2}$$
This equation Pell.  $q=10$  : $a=1$

So you need to solve the equation.

$$24x^2+2xy+y^2=2z^2$$

Using the formula the solution will be.  Reducing a common divisor.

$$x=(40\mp54)p^2+4(1\mp5)ps\mp{s^2}$$

$$y=-(230\pm54)p^2+4(1\mp5)ps+(5\mp1)s^2$$

$$z=54(5\mp1)p^2+2(27\mp10)ps+(5\mp1)s^2$$

Remember that  $y_1=x+y$  For the equation.

$$23x^2+y_1^2=2z^2$$

Finally the solution can be written as.

$$x=(40\mp54)p^2+4(1\mp5)ps\mp{s^2}$$

$$y_1=-(190\pm108)p^2+8(1\mp5)ps+(5\mp2)s^2$$

$$z=54(5\mp1)p^2+2(27\mp10)ps+(5\mp1)s^2$$

Comment: Thanks for providing a parameterisation of the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

$$98**2 + 23*14**2 = 2*84**2$$

These triples work too.

`1 23 78
3 1 4
5 7 24
6 2 8
7 1 6
9 3 12
9 17 58
10 14 48
12 4 16
14 2 12
15 5 20
15 7 26
15 21 72
18 6 24
20 28 96
21 3 18
21 7 28
24 8 32
25 1 18
27 9 36
28 4 24
30 10 40
30 14 52
33 11 44
35 5 30
36 12 48
39 13 52
42 6 36
42 14 56
45 1 32
45 15 60
45 21 78
48 16 64
49 7 42
50 2 36
51 17 68
54 18 72
56 8 48
57 19 76
59 7 48
60 20 80
61 17 72
63 9 54
63 21 84
66 22 88
69 23 92
70 10 60
72 24 96
75 3 54
77 11 66
81 7 62
84 12 72
90 2 64
91 13 78`

Program `dio.py`

`for k in range(100):
    for l in range(100):
        for m in range(100):
            if k*k + 23*l*l == 2*m*m:
                print(k,l,m)`

Comment: Thanks for the great help.

Comment: bad habit reward the result of a calculator

Comment: I will paste in my brute-force effort so you can see it.

Comment: excuse me but I did not offend you. I thought overall mod

Comment: $ \color{blue}{ \left(7u^2 + 10uv -3 v^2 \right)^2 + 23  \left(u^2 -2uv - v^2  \right)^2 = 8 \left( 3u^2 +  uv + 2 v^2 \right)^2}  $ gives all primitive solutions.