# Rational points on circles centered at the origin

Tags: number-theory

How can I determine if $x^2+y^2 = z$ has infinitely many rational solutions $(x,y)$ based on the value of $z\in \Bbb{Q}$.

I understand that $a^2+b^2=1$ has infinitely many rational solutions.  As does $a^2+b^2=2$.  However, $a^2+b^2=3$ has no rational solutions.  When $z$ is an integer I know how to determine if it has rational solutions.  However when $z$ is not an integer it is not clear when it has rational solutions.

For example, it is not immediately clear to me if the equation $$x^2+y^2 = \frac 43$$ has infinitely many rational solutions.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1513733/solving-a-diophantine-equation-of-the-form-x2-ay2-byz-cz2-with-the-co/1514030#1514030

Comment: For any $z > 0$, If it has one solution, it has infinitely many because there are infinitely many $u,v \in \mathbb{Q}$ satisfy $u^2+v^2=1$ and hence  $(xu-yv)^2 + (xv+yu)^2 = x^2+y^2 = z$.

Comment: @achillehui: how do you get the last identity ?

Comment: If there is one solution we can write the formula.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1513733/solving-a-diophantine-equation-of-the-form-x2-ay2-byz-cz2-with-the-co/1514052#1514052

Comment: Or more common there.  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/225781/fricke-klein-method-for-isotropic-ternary-quadratic-forms/225995#225995

Comment: @YvesDaoust $(x+iy)(u+iv) = (xu-yv)+(xv+yu)i$

Comment: @achillehui: where is $z$ gone, now ?

Comment: @achillehui: got it now, thanks. I was missing that is $x,y$ is the known solution.

Comment: @DanielW.Farlow I understand that $a^2+b^2=1$ has infinitely many rational solutions.  As does $a^2+b^2=2$.  However, $a^2+b^2=3$ has no rational solutions.  When $z$ is an integer I know how to determine if it has rational solutions.  However when $z$ is not an integer it is not clear when it has rational solutions.  Thanks.

Comment: @Ryan I wonder. I brought the formula and there is a solvability condition. What is not satisfied?

Comment: @individ - Thank you for continuing to try to help me with this problem.  Maybe I'm being slow, but I don't see how the solutions proposed on the other problem answer my question.  You say "I brought the formula and there is a solvability condition."  Can you please explain further?  What formula? And what is the solvability condition?  Perhaps if you can show me how you are able to determine if a circle of radius sqrt(4/3) has rational solutions this would help me.  Thanks again.