# How can I show $z^2 = 6x^2 + 2y^2$ has no non-trivial integer solutions?

Tags: number-theory, proof-writing, integers

EDIT: I missed a part of the question as there was a typo in my notes (this is part of my working on a proof using the Bruck–Ryser–Chowla theorem which was presented incorrectly in my version of the lecture notes). I have updated the question and shown some new working.

---

I was thinking of supposing that $x^2$, $y^2$ & $z^2$ have no common factors (because if they did, just divide out by that factor), and then considering possible solutions to $z^2 - 2y^2 = 6x^2$ modulo 6. See, we know $z^2 \equiv 2y^2 \mod 6$ which gives us six options.

- $z^2 \equiv 2y^2 \equiv 0 \mod 6$
- $z^2 \equiv 2y^2 \equiv 1 \mod 6$
- $z^2 \equiv 2y^2 \equiv 2 \mod 6$
- $z^2 \equiv 2y^2 \equiv 3 \mod 6$
- $z^2 \equiv 2y^2 \equiv 4 \mod 6$
- $z^2 \equiv 2y^2 \equiv 5 \mod 6$

In each case, I was thinking I could arrive to a contradiction, but I'm having a little trouble with the last five cases.

- Let $z^2 = 6 \alpha$ and $2y^2 = 6 \beta$. Then $x^2$, $y^2$ & $z^2$ all have a factor of 3 which is impossible.
- Let $z^2 = 6 \alpha + 1$ and $2y^2 = 6 \beta + 1$ ...
- Let $z^2 = 6 \alpha + 2$ and $2y^2 = 6 \beta + 2$ ...
- Let $z^2 = 6 \alpha + 3$ and $2y^2 = 6 \beta + 3$ ...
- Let $z^2 = 6 \alpha + 4$ and $2y^2 = 6 \beta + 4$ ...
- Let $z^2 = 6 \alpha + 5$ and $2y^2 = 6 \beta + 5$ ...

Any comments on the general proof structure or help with the last two cases would be greatly appreciated! Cheers.

Comment: The last case is easy to disprove because there exist no $n^2 \equiv 2 \mod 3$.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about that. I'll have to check that out.

Comment: One strategy could be to try to squeeze $6x^2+y^2$ strictly between two perfect squares, and then check the ones in between. I might try it on this problem when I have time.

Comment: Is $x = 4, y = 5, z = 11$ considered a trivial solution ?

Comment: found this one too $24+1=25\to(2,1,5)$

Comment: @user202729 sorry! There was a typo in my notes. I have updated the question and I would appreciate it if you maybe had another look. Cheers.

Comment: I always use this formula.   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1513733/solving-a-diophantine-equation-of-the-form-x2-ay2-byz-cz2-with-the-co/1514030#1514030

Comment: You can rule out three cases because, for example, $2y^2$ is even and $6k+1$ is odd.

Answer (score 2):

Assume $(x,y,z)$ is a solution to $z^2 = 6x^2 + 2y^2 $ with smallest positive $|z|$, then $\gcd(x,y) = 1$. Putting $z=2z_1$ gives
$$2z_1^ 2 = 3x^2 + y^2 $$ Since $x,y$ are both odd, RHS is divisible by $4$, so $z_1$ is even, that is $8\mid (2z_1^2)$. Hence $3x^2 + y^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{8}$. But the square of an odd number modolo $8$ must be $1$, a contradiction.

Hence $(0,0,0)$ is the only solution.

Comment: If x,y are odd, then z^2=6+2=0 (mod 8)

Comment: @Michael  Thanks for pointing this out, I edited my answer.