# rational solutions of the equation $3x^2-5y^2=3$

Tags: number-theory

Find all rational solutions of the equation

$$3x^2-5y^2=3$$

After a little bit of calculations I have managed to find a single pair $(4,3)$. I have heard about something called rational points on curves (e.g. circle).

Is there some "general algorithm" for solving this kind of problems?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2773097/how-to-find-all-rational-solutions-of-x2-3y2-7/2788381#2788381

Comment: $x=\pm 1, y=0$ also solves it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any rational solution $(x,y)$ must satisfy $$y-3=m(x-4)$$ for some rational number $m$.  Now, write $3x^2-5y^2=3$ as
$$3(x-4)(x+4)-5(y-3)(y+3)=0\,.$$
Thus, for a solution $(x,y)\neq (4,3)$, we have
$$3(x+4)-5m(y+3)=0\,.$$
Plugging in $y=3+m(x-4)$, we get
$$-\left(5m^2-3\right)x+\left(20m^2-30m+12\right)=3(x+4)-5m\big(6+m(x-4)\big)=0\,.$$
That is,
$$x=\frac{20m^2-30m+12}{5m^2-3}\,.$$
Then, you can solve for $y$, using $y=3+m(x-4)$.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the first point you can do it (for conics).  If there is another point $(x,y)$ on the curve with rational coordinates, then the equation of the line through $(x,y)$ and $(4,3)$ obviously has rational coefficients.  Conversely, a line with rational slope through (4,3) intersects the curve in another point with rational coordinates (unless it happens to be the tangent.)

Look at [these notes](http://math.rice.edu/~evanmb/math499spring10/vigrenotes3.pdf) for an example with a circle.