# Solve Diophantine equation with three variables

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, pell-type-equations

I am trying to generate all primitive solutions less than a certain limit for the following Diophantine equation.
$$x^2−y^2−z^2−xy−yz−zx=0$$
Using brute force, it seems that $x$ always takes the form $a^2+ab+b^2$ with $(a,b)=1$, $y$ and $z$ take the form $a^2-ab+b^2$ with $(a,b)=1$.

So far I have been unable to find a concrete parametric solutions. Any help will be much appreciated.

Edit: I was not far from solution. All primitive triples can be generated by $(a^2+ab+b^2,a^2+ab-b^2,b^2+ab-a^2)$ with $a>b$ and $(a,b)=1$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2773097/how-to-find-all-rational-solutions-of-x2-3y2-7/2788381#2788381

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$x^2-x(y+z)−y^2−z^2−yz=0\hspace{1cm} /\cdot 4$$

$$4x^2-4x(y+z)−4y^2−4z^2−4yz=0$$

$$\underbrace{4x^2-4x(y+z)+\color{red}{(y+z)^2}}-\color{red}{(y+z)^2}−4y^2−4z^2−4yz=0$$

$$(2x-y-z)^2−5y^2−5z^2−6yz=0\hspace{1cm} /\cdot 5$$

$$5(2x-y-z)^2− \underbrace{ 25y^2−30yz \color{red}{-9z^2}}+\color{red}{9z^2}−25z^2=0$$

$$5(2x-y-z)^2−(5y+3z)^2−16z^2=0$$

So, if $a=2x-y-z$ and $b=5y+3z$ and $c=4z$ then you have to solve this Pell-s equation: $$5a^2=b^2+c^2$$

Comment: Wow. Awesome solution @Aqua

Answer (score 2):

This is the homogeneous equation of a projective conic. The standard recipe for a rational parametrization of such curves is to

1. Find at least one rational point on the curve (by, e.g., using linear coordinate transformations to reduce it to the Legendre form
   $$A X^2 + BY^2 + C Z^2 =0$$
   and using the Hasse local-global principle), then
2. using stereographic projection from that point to produce the parametrization.

In the present case we can see that
$$[x : y : z]=[1 : -1 : 1]$$
is a solution; stereographic projection onto $y=0$, say, gives
$$[x : y : z] =
[ a^2-ab+b^2 : b^2 - ab - a^2 : a^2 - ab - b^2 ]\text{.}$$

Edit: it should be noted that parametrizing projective conics is routine enough to be relegated to a computer algebra system. For example, in [Magma](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/) the input

```
k := Rationals();
P2<x,y,z> := ProjectiveSpace(k, 2);
f := x^2 - y^2 - z^2 - x*y - x*z - y*z;
C := Conic(P2, f);
P1<t,u> := ProjectiveSpace(k, 1);
Parametrization(C, Curve(P1));
```

gives

```
Mapping from: Curve over Rational Field defined by
0 to CrvCon: C
with equations :
t^2 + t*u + u^2
-t^2 + t*u + u^2
-t^2 - 3*t*u - u^2
and inverse
2*x - 2*y
-2*x - 2*z
and alternative inverse equations :
-2*x - 2*z
4*x + 2*y + 2*z
```

i.e.,

$$\begin{align}
[ x : y : z] &=
[ t^2 + tu + u^2 :
-t^2 + tu + u^2 :
-t^2 - 3tu - u^2 ] \\
[t : u ] &= [ 2x - 2y : -2x - 2z ]
\end{align}$$